# Properly measure execution time for benchmarking

Tags: command-line, 18.04, performance

I hope this is the correct place to ask this question.

I would like to benchmark a program using some test instances. I’m primarily interested in the cpu time the program took to execute and to this end, I’ve found the `time` command that gives me the real, user and sys time. As I’m quite new to linux, I’m not sure which of these to take. For me, user and sys seem to be my best bet, but I’m not quite sure which one to take. Does it make sense to add them up to get the total cpu-seconds or is user the most meaningful in my application?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Or, you could use `/usr/bin/time` instead of the `bash` builtin `time`. Read `man time`. What is the goal of these "benchmarks"?

Answer (score 1):

By default, there are two `time` commands on your system:

- a `bash` shell keyword
  This is called when you run `time`, you can get help about it with `help time`. If you want to tweak its output, read about the `TIMEFORMAT` variable in `man bash`.
- a binary `/usr/bin/time`
  If you want this you need to call it with its full path, you can get help about it with [`man time`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/time.1.html).

The `/usr/bin/time` binary comes with a nice `-f, --format` option which lets you choose the information in its output. The mentioned manpage has the full list of specifiers under `FORMATTING THE OUTPUT`, here are just some suggestions that may be relevant for you:

> **K** Average total (data+stack+text) memory use of the process, in Kilobytes.
>   **S** Total number of CPU-seconds used by the system on behalf of the process (in kernel mode), in seconds.
>   **U** Total number of CPU-seconds that the process used directly (in user mode), in seconds.

If `S` and `U` is what’s important in your case and you want those two on separate lines, your command line could look like this:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%S\n%U" /path/to/program
```

As `S` and `U` are available for `bash`’s `time` as well, this translates to:

```
TIMEFORMAT=$'%S\n%U' && time /path/to/program
```

It’s worth noting that the `bash` keyword is able to output milliseconds while the binary does only output centiseconds. The keyword may also be faster, as no external program needs to be called.

For an overview on the timing topic, I recommend reading [`man 7 time`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man7/time.7.html).